# I get an error while mocking the .net core Identity Rolemanager object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, mocking, moq

My problem is as follows. I have a method called GetListAsync() in Roleservice. This method returns a list of roles. For the sake of example, imagine I have a code like this

var roles = await _roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();
return roles;

How can I commit a Roles property to mock.

I would be very happy if you can help

```
public class RoleService : IRoleService
{
    private readonly RoleManager<Role> _roleManager;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public RoleService(RoleManager<Role> roleManager, IMapper mapper = null)
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    public async Task<List<RoleDto>> GetListAsync()
    {

        var roles = await _roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();

        if (roles == null)
            throw new NotFoundException(ResponseCode.Exception, ErrorMessageKey.ROLE_NOTFOUND);

        return _mapper.Map<List<RoleDto>>(roles);
    }
 }
```

Test Code

```
 public class RoleServiceTest
{
    private Mock<RoleManager<Role>> _mockRoleManager;
    private RoleManager<Role> _roleManager;
    private RoleService _roleService;
    private IMapper _mapper;

    private readonly List<Role> _roles;

    public RoleServiceTest()
    {
        var myProfile = new MappingProfile();
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(myProfile));
        _mapper = new Mapper(configuration);
        _mockRoleManager = GetRoleManagerMock();
        _roleManager = _mockRoleManager.Object;
        _roleService = new RoleService(_roleManager, _mapper);

        _roles = GetFakerRoles();
    }

  

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetListAsync_ValidInput_RoleDto()
    {
        // mocking code 

        var result = await _roleService.GetListAsync();

        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.IsType<List<RoleDto>>(result);
    }

   

    private Mock<RoleManager<Role>> GetRoleManagerMock()
    {
        

        return new Mock<RoleManager<Role>>(
            new Mock<IRoleStore<Role>>().Object,
            new IRoleValidator<Role>[0],
            new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
            new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
            new Mock<ILogger<RoleManager<Role>>>().Object);
    }

    private List<Role> GetFakerRoles()
    {
        return new Faker<Role>()
             .RuleFor(r => r.Id, f => f.Random.Guid().ToString())
             .RuleFor(r => r.Name, f => f.Random.Words())
             .RuleFor(r => r.NormalizedName, (f, r) => r.Name.ToUpper())
             .RuleFor(r => r.ConcurrencyStamp, f => f.Random.ToString())
             .Generate(4);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `Roles` type here?

Comment: Hi @Bayram Eren, how is your mock code like? What's the error message?

Comment: Hi @Rena System.InvalidOperationException : The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable<AuthService.Core.DataModel.Role>. Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

Comment: Hi @BayramEren, it is better for you to share the code about how do you mock the RoleManager...

Comment: now i shared...

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create a mock object for the RoleManager class
var mockRoleManager = new Mock<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

// Setup the Roles property to return a list of roles
var roles = new List<IdentityRole> { new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" }, new IdentityRole { Name = "User" } };
mockRoleManager.Setup(x => x.Roles).Returns(roles);

// Inject the mock object into your service or component that uses the RoleManager
var service = new MyService(mockRoleManager.Object);

// Now you can use the mock object to test your service or component
var result = await service.GetListAsync();

// Assert that the result is the expected list of roles
Assert.AreEqual(result, roles);
```

Comment: pretty close, but not exactly.  what we'll need here is `.Returns(roles)` to return a collection type that supports `GetListAsync`.  i.e, `mockRoleManager.Roles.GetListAsync` should return `Task<List<IdentityRole>>`.  `RoleService` (as referenced by OP) is going to be calling and resolving in the scope of methods of that service, which may or may not include exposing a service method called `GetListAsync` itself.

Comment: It asks me for IQueryable<IdentityRole> in the returns section.

Comment: Roles itself dbset normally does not have such a method GetListAsync. Do you want me to write an extension for this?